# win_shell command unbalanced jinja2 - works with c:\temp but not c:\

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am getting the following error:

> ERROR! failed at splitting arguments, either an unbalanced jinja2
> block or quotes: Expand-Archive -LiteralPath 'c:\my_data.zip'
> -DestinationPath 'c:\' -Force

I have narrowed it down, and its coming from win_shell.

This one works:

```
Expand-Archive -LiteralPath 'c:\temp\my_data.zip' -DestinationPath 'c:\temp' -Force
```

And this one doesnt and give the reported Jinja error:

```
Expand-Archive -LiteralPath 'c:\my_data.zip' -DestinationPath 'c:\' -Force
```

Why is this happening? They both contain c:\ in them, just one has a 'temp' folder and the other doesn't.

What can I do to fix this win_shell code? I've tried "escaping" the c:\ into c:\ \

**Here is the full code:**

This code *works fine* when i specify a **c:\temp** directory

```
 - name: Creating destination directory for install_my_data_1655833375
  win_file:
    path: c:\temp
    state: directory

- name: Copying install_my_data_1655833375 folder or file
  win_copy:
    src: install_my_data_1655833375/my_data.zip
    dest: c:\temp\my_data.zip

- name: Unarchiving install_my_data_1655833375 folder or file
  win_shell: |
    Expand-Archive -LiteralPath 'c:\temp\my_data.zip' -DestinationPath 'c:\temp' -Force

- name: Removing install_my_data_1655833375 archive folder that was extracted prior
  win_file:
    path: c:\temp\my_data.zip
    state: absent
```

But when I try to execute the same logic but at the root of c:\ I get *the fail*

```
- name: Creating destination directory for install_my_data_1655833375
  win_file:
    path: c:\
    state: directory

- name: Copying install_my_data_1655833375 folder or file
  win_copy:
    src: install_my_data_1655833375/my_data.zip
    dest: c:\my_data.zip

- name: Unarchiving install_my_data_1655833375 folder or file
  win_shell: |
    Expand-Archive -LiteralPath 'c:\my_data.zip' -DestinationPath 'c:\' -Force

- name: Removing install_my_data_1655833375 archive folder that was extracted prior
  win_file:
    path: c:\my_data.zip
    state: absent
```

Edit: For further context, in generating the above code with a jinja template, so I’m trying to avoid creating “special cases”/one-offs. The single quotes have worked in all cases, including file paths with spaces. But I just found the example where this doesn’t work so nicely, when I’m extracting directly to C:\

Comment: have you try c:\.

Comment: Because the backslash escapes the quote. You need to double it: `'c:\\'`

Answer (score 0):

i dont understant why `'c:\\'` is not ok for you, so
in my sample, you could work with / instead of \

```
Expand-Archive -LiteralPath 'c:\temp\my_data.zip' -DestinationPath 'c:/' -Force
```

Comment: I tried ‘c:\\’ as the destination but I still get the error. I don’t mind escaping, it just doesn’t prevent the error I’m seeing